# Making id case-insensitive but case-preserving in endpoints-proto-datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I'm trying to define a model whose `id` is case-insensitive but case-preserving, and the below *nearly* works:

```
class MyModel(endpoints_ndb.EndpointsModel):

    _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'name')

    caseful_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

    def IdSet(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, basestring):
            raise TypeError('ID must be a string.')
        self.caseful_id = value
        self.UpdateFromKey(ndb.Key(self.__class__, value.lower()))

    @endpoints_ndb.EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=IdSet)
    def id(self):
        return self.caseful_id
```

Creating a new instance stores the `id` in lowercase, with the original capitalisation in `caseful_id`, and fetching a list returns the original capitalisations, but requesting a specific model by `id` with:

```
@MyModel.method(request_fields=('id',), path='mymodel/{id}',
                http_method='GET', name='mymodel.get')
def MyModelGet(self, mymodel):
    if not mymodel.from_datastore:
        raise endpoints.NotFoundException('MyModel not found.')
    return mymodel
```

always returns the same `id` that was given in the request, with the same capitalisation. Is there a way to make it actually call the `id` getter function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setter is being called, and it is causing the behavior you don't want. Tearing it down:

```
def IdSet(self, value):
    if not isinstance(value, basestring):
        raise TypeError('ID must be a string.')
    self.caseful_id = value
    self.UpdateFromKey(ndb.Key(self.__class__, value.lower()))
```

since you call

```
self.caseful_id = value
```

before `UpdateFromKey`, the `caseful_id` will always be the one from the most recent request.

Bear in mind that `UpdateFromKey` tries to retrieve an entity by that key and then patches in any **missing** data from the entity stored in the datastore (and also sets `from_datastore` to `True`).

Since you set the `caseful_id` field **before** `UpdateFromKey`, there is no missing data. Instead, you could do this to set the value if not already set (and so this wouldn't be relevant for your `'GET'` method):

```
def IdSet(self, value):
    if not isinstance(value, basestring):
        raise TypeError('ID must be a string.')
    self.UpdateFromKey(ndb.Key(self.__class__, value.lower()))
    if self.caseful_id is None:
        self.caseful_id = value
```